# Stop redirect to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https, virtualhost

A year ago, I redirected http to https by having the following in the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

I commented it out.  But when I enter my URL in a browser, it still redirects to https.  I commented out some more from the .htaccess , as shown below with the "####":

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set variable for https to be used by domain rewrites
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Source: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/http-https-rewriterule-redirect.html
# Use Case: http%{ENV:https}://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}

#### RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}s ^(443(s)|[0-9]+s)$
#### RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=https:%2]

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Prevent fully qualified domain names (trailing "." in HTTP_HOST)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Prevent possible issues such as duplicate content appearing search engines
# Read more at http://saynt2day.blogspot.ru/2013/03/danger-of-trailing-dot-in-domain-name.html

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.$
#### RewriteRule ^.*$ http%{ENV:https}://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Suppress or force the "www." at the beginning of URLs
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# The same content should never be available under two different URLs -
# especially not with and without "www." at the beginning, since this can cause
# SEO problems (duplicate content). That's why you should choose one of the
# alternatives and redirect the other one.

# By default option 1 (no "www.") is activated.
# no-www.org/faq.php?q=class_b

# If you'd prefer to use option 2, just comment out all option 1 lines
# and uncomment option 2.

# IMPORTANT: NEVER USE BOTH RULES AT THE SAME TIME!

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Option 1:
# Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com".

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  #### RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  #### RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:https}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule rewrite_module>
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
####  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
####  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it still redirects to https.  I removed the `<VirtualHost *:443>` section from the Apache virtual host file.  I ran sudo a2dissite, sudo a2ensite and sudo service apache2 restart.  Nevertheless, it still redirects to https.

Can anyone provide suggestions on how to stop this redirect?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache? 301 (`[R]`) redirect is permanent.

Comment: @arco444  Yes, cleared it in Chrome and Firefox.  Still redirects.  However, I just found out that it does not redirect on Safari.  Strange.  Are you saying that "R=301" forces the user's browser to permanently redirect even after the line is commented out?

Comment: Yes, 301 redirects are cached. However, clearing the cache should stop it from happening so it's odd that it doesn't work after that.